# Javascript action on bookmark click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am running a Wordpress site (Divi themes), and it has the ability to add code to specific pages.  I have a page with a left sidebar showing the table of contents, a middle text with a description, and a right sidebar with an example.  The site is here: logan.pverify.com/rest-api.

When the user clicks on the table of contents, it's a hyperlink bookmark #foo.  That part is fine.  But I want javascript to launch and display code examples on the right sidebar (i envision this to be a series of divs that are hidden or visible).  There are only 5 or so sections to the whole thing so it's not all that bad.

Anyway.  I can't figure out if it is even possible to do this.  I managed to get js code working.  Laughable, but it's a start.  I am mostly a C# winforms guy.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    alert('hello');
});
</script>
```

Comment: So, essentially, the question is how to show a hidden DIV element on click of a different, visible element?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am not sure!  Can we tie the table of contents into an ID so that each ID has an on-click event?

Comment: You don't *need* to tie the table's contents to IDs specifically, you can use all sorts of different CSS selectors. You can target via class, attribute, tag name... and even use the pseudo-class `:nth-of-type()` to target specific rows. You shouldn't need to change your HTML at all; simply adjust your selector to target the relevant element that you want to hide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is first make the element hidden by default in the CSS, and then attach a click event handler to the visible element with the **[`.on() method`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**. This handler should change the CSS `display` property of the invisible element (in this example, to `block`) with use of the **[`.css() method`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

```js
$("#visible").on("click", function() {
  $("#hidden").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="visible">
  Visible
</button>

<div id="hidden">
  Hidden content
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks.  The table of contents is a list.  Can I convert each list item into a button?  Is it only a button that could have a onclick event?

Comment: Any HTML element can have an `onclick` handler, not just buttons. Also, it would be quite trivial to style a `li` tag to look like a button using `css` without having to use a `button` tag in its place

Comment: It's exactly as @kharhys says; **any** element can have an `on()` handler (or `onclick`). The fact that I used a button makes no difference; the 'trigger' is simply applying to whatever element has the ID `visible` in my example. If you make your `<ul>` or `<li>` have the ID `hidden`, it will work. However, note that you can't have **multiple** IDs with the same name; you'll need to use different IDs for each `<li>` element (or use classes or `:nth-of-type` instead). If you update your question to showcase your exact structure, I can provide you the exact code you'll need :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give a unique `id` and a `class=bookmark` to each of the hidden `div` that you envision that corresponds with a hyperlink bookmark on the table of content. For instance, the link #foo should have a hidden div with id `foo`. Add an `onclick=showSection(this)` handler to each link in the table of content and a function `showSection` that looks like

```
function showSection(link) {
  var bookmark = $(link).attr('href').split('#')[1] //find clicked section
  $('.bookmark').show() // hide all sections
  $('#' + bookmark).show() //show only clicked section
}
```

I assume the bookmark links are html `anchor` tags in the form `foo.com/#bar`

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML

```
<div class="form" id="form1">Form 1</div>
<div class="form" id="form2">Form 2</div>
<div class="form" id="form3">Form 3</div>

<div class="nav">
     <a href="#form1">click to see #form1</a>
     <a href="#form2">click to see #form2</a>
     <a href="#form3">click to see #form3</a>
</div>
```

#### jquery

$(".nav a").click(function(){

```
    var attr = $(this).attr("href");
    $(attr).show();
    $(attr).siblings(".form").hide();
    

});
```

#### Css

```
.form{
   display:none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#form1{
    background-color: red;
}

#form2{
    background-color: blue;
}

#form3{
    background-color: black;
}
```

#### Working Example

http://jsfiddle.net/8u7n2/

### This will just hight light the div

http://jsfiddle.net/3gkAV/

They are two different examples and will give you a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a few things, which I thought I would mention.  Again this is for a wordpress site.  The net effect is that the "main" TOC headers will link to that section of the text as a bookmark.  The code will show all the divs.  The subheaders with individual endpoint documentation will hide all the divs except for one main and one example. So the net effect is that at the top of the page you can see both an example and description.  Thanks to everyone, this is probably a mix of what everyone was thinking.

On the left there is a sidebar for the table of contents, and it's code is here:

```
<a href="#Overview" onclick="showAll()" >Overview</a>
<br>
<a href="#ClientLibraries" onclick="showAll()" >Client Libraries</a>
<br>
<a href="#Security" onclick="showAll()" >Security and Authorization</a>
<br>
&emsp; &emsp;<a href="#Token" onclick="showBookmark(this)">Token</a>
<br>
<a href="#Endpoints" onclick="showAll()" >Available API Endpoints</a>
<br>
&emsp; &emsp; <a href="#EligibilityInquiry" onclick="showBookmark(this)">EligibilityInquiry</a>
<br>
&emsp; &emsp;
<a href="#GetEligibilityInquiry" onclick="showBookmark(this)">GetEligibilityInquiry</a>
<br>
&emsp; &emsp;
<a href="#GetPayers" onclick="showBookmark(this)">GetPayers</a>
```

The main body has code like this:

```
<p id="Overview" /> <div id="OverviewMain" class="bookmark" style="display: block;"> </div>
```

The right sidebar with the examples has code like this:

```
<div id="TokenExample" class="bookmark" style="display: none;"> </div>
```

And the JS is in a code module in Divi.

```
<script>
function showBookmark(link) {

   var bookmark = jQuery(link).attr('href').split('#')[1]; //find clicked section
   jQuery('.bookmark').css("display", "none"); // hide all sections
   jQuery('#' + bookmark  + 'Example').show();
   jQuery('#' + bookmark  + 'Main').show();
 }
function showAll() {
   jQuery('.bookmark').css("display", "block"); // show all sections
}
</script>
```